# ORACLE: Splitting a string into multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to split a string "HHHWWWHHHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHH"
is there any possibility to make like :

```
H
H
H
W
W
W
```

---

```
BRANCH_CODE  YEAR   MONTH   HOLIDAY_LIST
1   001      2021   1        HHHWWWHHHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHH
2   001      2021   2        WWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWHWWWHH
```

[image]

Comment: Be clear about the DB (Oracle / MySQL) and its version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT branch_code, year, month, day, holiday
FROM   branches
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL AS day,
                SUBSTR(holiday_list, LEVEL, 1) AS holiday
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(holiday_list)
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE branches (BRANCH_CODE, YEAR, MONTH, HOLIDAY_LIST) AS
SELECT '001', 2021, 1, 'HHHWWWHHHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '001', 2021, 2, 'WWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWHWWWHH'    FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | BRANCH_CODE | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOLIDAY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 001 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | H |
> | 001 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | H |
> | 001 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | H |
> | 001 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | W |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | 001 | 2021 | 1 | 29 | W |
> | 001 | 2021 | 1 | 30 | H |
> | 001 | 2021 | 1 | 31 | H |
> | 001 | 2021 | 2 | 1 | W |
> | 001 | 2021 | 2 | 2 | W |
> | 001 | 2021 | 2 | 3 | W |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | 001 | 2021 | 2 | 26 | W |
> | 001 | 2021 | 2 | 27 | H |
> | 001 | 2021 | 2 | 28 | H |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=192f32b05ea53db8be92756e9f7fff5b)*

Comment: @FeliksBekeshov Use `TO_DATE` on the concatenation of the `year`, `month` and `day` columns if you want a single column containing a date. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=292b73c6484f44e58e681615815bb8d1)

Answer (score 0):

If it's Oracle:

```
with data AS (
select 'WWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWHWWWHH' AS letters 
from dual
)
select substr (
           letters,
           level,
           1
         ) value
from data
connect by level <= 
    length ( letters )
```

Comment: but i can not add a date there yeah?

Comment: While this may work for a single row of input, if there are multiple rows of input then the hierarchical query has no way to maintain the correlation from one level of the current row to the next level and so it will correlate each row with **ALL** previously generated rows at the prior level and you will get exponentially increasing numbers of duplicate rows.